# Find a tight frame in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with 10 elements of lengths $\{ \mathscr{L}_1,\dots,\mathscr{L}_{10} \}$, with

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

1. Find a tight frame in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with 10 elements of lengths $\{ \mathscr{L}_1,\dots,\mathscr{L}_{10} \}$, with $\mathscr{L}_1=1$, $\mathscr{L}_2=2$, $\dots$, $\mathscr{L}_{10}=10$.
2. Is it possible to find a tight frame in $\mathbb{R}^2$ made of four vectors with $\mathscr{L}_1=1$, $\mathscr{L}_2=2$, and $\mathscr{L}_3=3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Part A:}$ Let 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
r_1 & =\{ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \sqrt{2}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}, 2\sqrt{2}, \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \sqrt{2}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}, 2\sqrt{2}, \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}  \} \\
r_2 & =\{ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \sqrt{2}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}, 2\sqrt{2}, \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\sqrt{2}, -\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}, -2\sqrt{2}, -\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}  \} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$\begin{Bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & 2\sqrt{2} & \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & 2\sqrt{2} & \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & 2\sqrt{2} & \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\sqrt{2} & -\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & -2\sqrt{2} & -\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{Bmatrix}$

1. $\|r_1\|=\|r_2\|$

$$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2+(\sqrt{2})^2+\cdots+(\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}})^2=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2+(\sqrt{2})^2+\cdots+(-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}})^2$$
which is true.

2. $\langle r_1,r_2 \rangle =0$

$$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})+\cdots+(\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}})(\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}})+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})+\cdots+(\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}})(-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}})=0$$

$\textbf{Part B:}$

$\begin{Bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & a_1 \\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & a_2
\end{Bmatrix}$

$$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2+(\sqrt{2})^2+(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}})^2=\frac{1}{2}+2+\frac{9}{2}=7$$

So $a^2=7$ implies $a_1=\sqrt{7}$ and $a_1=-\sqrt{7}$, where $a_i$ are the roots of a.